# Uso de "r" como "rr" tras consonante en el español medieval

Tags: ortografía, historia, pronunciación, letras, escritura

Siguiendo con la saga de preguntas sobre "r/rr", buscando en el CORDE me di cuenta de que hay muchos textos de alrededor de los siglo XV y XVI que contienen una "rr" tras consonante cuando debería ser una "r" (negritas mías):

> *... non enbargante que por su hesleymiento e **nonbrramiento** para procurador syndico de la dicha villa...* (1514)
> <sub><sup>Pleito [Colección documental del Archivo Histórico de Bilbao]</sup></sub>
>
> *... a los quales interpusyese su **decrreto** e autoridad e liçençia para que baliesen...* (1482)
> <sub><sup>Solicitud de documentos [Colección documental del archivo municipal de Lequeitio]</sup></sub>
>
> *Primeramente, se repartio en el **padrron** prinçipal a falta de propios y rentas...* (1508)
> <sub><sup>Libro de visitas del corregidor [Colección documental del archivo municipal de Lequeitio]</sup></sub>
>
> *... eçeçion del enganno e **frraude** e dolo malo e a la gesion de...* (1448)
> <sub><sup>Carta de obligación [Colección documental del Archivo Municipal de Mondragón]</sup></sub>
>
> *... e podades gosar de todas las honrras e **grraçias** e merçedes e prehemirençias...* (1477)
> <sub><sup>Carta de merced de alcaldía de lo morisco a don Hurtado de Mendoza [Tumbo de los Reyes Católicos del Concejo de Sevilla]</sup></sub>

Bueno, y así sucesivamente. ¿A qué se debe que se encuentren palabras escritas así durante estos siglos? Nótese que en los ejemplos sí aparecen palabras como *autoridad*, e incluso *propios* (que no duplica la "r"), *rentas* (que no tiene "rr" inicial como en otros textos). ¿Es un error de transcripción debido al estilo de escritura de la época? ¿Se corresponde con una pronunciación diferente de la "r" tras consonante, que podría ser más marcada en algunos reinos de España? ¿Es simplemente que se escribía así en alguna de las variantes de los reinos?

Pistas que no sé si tendrán alguna relevancia:

- Casi todos los textos mencionados como ejemplos se enmarcan en textos catalogados como "documentos notariales". Otros están como "códigos y ordenamientos legales", y otros tipos similares.
- Casi todos los ejemplos encontrados son de textos en archivos del País Vasco (justo acabo de encontrar uno en un archivo de Sevilla, aunque en algunos textos que estudian y citan el "Tumbo" la palabra "grraçias" aparece transcrita como "graçias", así que este caso hay que cogerlo con pinzas).

Comment: El estilo de escritura de estos habrían sido más o menos lo tal como hoy, menos lo de nonbrramiento que probablmente se escribió con la r rotunda en la primera: nonbꝛramiento, y posiblemente con tildes así: nõbꝛramiẽto.  Pero la r simple y la doble se distingue fácilmente en los manuscritos.  Una pregunta que nos tendría que hacer es si es un error singular o si era algo de uso extendido dentro de un texto.  El primer ejemplo parece tener fuertes influencias galaicoportugueses

Comment: Esto sí que es raro, Charlie. A diferencia de la *rr* inicial o tras *n/s/l*, que podría encuadrarse en la respuesta a tu otra pregunta, aquí hay un innovación ortográfica que no parece motivada por nada.

Comment: ¿Sería acaso que la rr estaba de moda con ciertos notarios?  ¿O que les daba cierto placer escribir?  ¿Podrías incluir una imagen con la letra así como se escribió a mano?

Comment: @aparente001 eso es justo lo que llevo un rato intentando encontrar: una imagen de cualquier manuscrito original que contenga la palabra escrita así, pero sin resultados de momento. Curiosamente, he visto una transcripción con notas que dice: "... e cosas que se _(tachado: prro)_ probeieren e mandaren...", es decir, como si en ese caso el escriba se arrepintiese de ponerlo con dos erres, aunque en el resto del documento se hiciese así.

Comment: Qué pena, otra recompensa que se pierde. Confirmado: cuando hay más de una a la vez, el resultado es peor.

Comment: @fedorqui lo siento, intenté buscar algo de documentación pero no vi nada concluyente, y además no le he podido dedicar mucho tiempo.

Comment: @Charlie faltaría más hombre! Si lo decía en general, el mérito tuya ya está sobradamente demostrado con esta y con las mil otras que publicas. Lo que aspiraba es a que alguien más (léase guifa o algún otro :D) pudiera investigar algo.

Comment: El RAE no existía hasta el 1713.  Yo creo que la cuestión debería ser cómo era el sistema de estandardización del castellano en aquella época.  Esto podría explicar las disparidades en los ejemplos mencionados.

Comment: Solo un dato: Menos la última, todas las citas corresponden a áreas con influencia euskera, y la mayoría de los que hablan este idioma tienen una forma peculiar de pronunciar esas erres después de consonantes ¿oclusivas? Podéis buscar algún vídeo en Internet para ver a lo que me refiero.

Comment: Hay que notar que en los documentos gubernamentales, incluso actualmente en muchos países latinoamericanos, pueden haber faltas ortográficas y de redacción bastante serias, por lo que ese documento no necesariamente refleje la práctica ortográfica de ese periodo de tiempo.

Comment: Errores de digitalización. Los manuscritos y documentos antigos se pasan por un escáner de libros de alta velocidad para la digitalización. Y esto crea errores que deben ser corrigidos manualmente. Ver este artículo: https://www.dlib.org/dlib/march09/landon/03landon.html

Comment: ¿Has notado donde caen estos errores? Solo despues de consonantes. ¿ No te parece estraño? No creo que son faltas de redacción.

Answer (score 2):

**Planteamiento**: La rr en la Edad Media

---

La grafía doble en el Español Medieval no es solo exclusiva de la "rr" sino que existen similitudes paleográficas con otras grafías geminadas. Así contamos además de la rr con la ss, la ff, la ll e incluso con la nn, aunque en este último caso posee unas características especiales que al final, parece ser, acabo por convertirse en el sonido "ñ".

La geminación de "**geminatio**" (*duplicación*) es un alargamiento de consonantes y por decirlo así, cada país ha ido desarrollando su propia historia de la Lengua y por tanto en cada lugar existen variaciones lingüísticas con sus correspondientes limitaciones fonológicas. De lo que si podemos sacar de la comparativa de estas lenguas, para intentar comprender la nuestra, a pesar de la distancia, es que depende del idioma esa "geminatio" podrá entenderse, según las circunstancias, de una u otra forma, es decir, a veces esa duplicación refuerza la longitud de una consonante distintiva y otras veces la duplicación se apoya para expresar cierta fuerza ó longitud de la vocal, como una especie de señal ó distintivo, hoy en día prácticamente en desuso.

En el caso Español podemos observar en el siguiente gráfico de Documentos Notariales en Castilla, como a lo largo de la Edad Media estas grafías dobles, que aparecen situadas dentro de la palabra en cualquier posición, van decayendo en número casi hasta el final de la época Medieval y solo se mantienen con cierta holgura la doble "l" ó "ll" con un 21,8% y la doble "r" ó "rr" con un 7%.

[image: Grafías dobles en Documentos Notariales en Castilla por mil palabras]

*Grafías dobles encontradas en Documentos Notariales en Castilla por cada mil palabras*

---

Salvando las grandes diferencias temporales, se cree que estos casos de doble grafía representaban ó señalaban, según las ocasiones, un sonido fuerte que marcaba la vocal siguiente como tónica, frente a las demás sílabas átonas, ya que en esta etapa las tildes ó acentos gráficos, tal y como los conocemos hoy en día no existían. Será a partir de 1713 cuando la academia de la Lengua comience a dar sus primeros pasos, pues los signos existentes anteriores no suelen ser considerados como acento en estricto sentido.

Desde un punto de vista fonológico esto nos puede ayudar a entender, aunque no de manera precisa, entre otras razones, por la disparidad regional, el cambio fonético y la posición del acento prosódico de algunas palabras que hoy han cambiado.

Siguiendo este análisis podríamos entender que la palabra "nonbrramiento", la sílaba tónica sería "bra" y no como en la actualidad que la sílaba tónica sería "mien" y la letra tónica "e". Sin embargo, las siguientes palabras "decrreto", "padrron", "frraude" ó "grraçias", su sílaba tónica ó de más fuerza, si corresponde con el acento prosódico ó gráfico si estás lo llevan.

- decrreto / **decreto** "cre", sílaba tónica, "e", letra tónica.
- padrron / **padrón** "drón", sílaba tónica, "o", letra tónica (entiendo que es el padrón de habitantes).
- frraude / **fraude** "frau", sílaba tónica, "u", letra tónica.
- grraçias / **gracias** "gra", sílaba tónica, "a", letra tónica.

Imagino que este tipo de Documentos Notariales, al ser redactados dentro de un "Cuerpo Jurídico", por el valor, precisión y con la previsión de ser un lenguaje más cuidado en su redacción al igual que puntilloso, de ahí que sea al menos uno de los motivos, donde se encuentre el mayor numero de estas variantes.

Answer (score -1):

Aquí incluyo una imagen de la escritura de un libro de 1552 de Fray Bartolomé de las Casas, quien era un erudito y cronista religioso e histórico, para comparar la ortografía.
[image]